# IOS 11 Review page not opening

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios11

I was able to open review page in app store with the code below with IOS 10 but not anymore in IOS 11.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=xxxxxxxx&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2&mt=8"]]];
```

How to do it in IOS 11?

Comment: see this http://blog.mallow-tech.com/2017/04/how-to-add-in-app-rating-to-your-app-in-ios-10-3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method of opening the review page with a URL is deprecated. From iOS version 10.3 and above, Apple instructed developers to use the [`SKStore​Review​Controller`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller):

> `SKStore​Review​Controller`: An object that controls the process of requesting App Store ratings and reviews from users.

Objective-C Usage code:

```
// Import the store kit 
@import StoreKit

// Use the controller to open the review URL
[SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
```

Comment: If you want to continue redirecting users to your store review page from a button inside your app, use the new URL : `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myAppName/idxxxxxxxxx?action=write-review&mt=8`

Comment: I tried this but its not opening to the "Review section" on iOS 11. (There is no separate tab for Reviews in App Store page anymore, so that could be a reason).